# Handle message versioning in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, messaging

I have set up several **microservices**, which interact with each other through a Message broker (**RabbitMQ**).

I have created a common **NuGet package** in which all the message objects are located inside this project.

For Example in this Nuget package we have

```
public class OrderCreatedMessage{ //some properties here}

public class OrderRemovedMessage{//some properties here}
```

and all the microservices use this package to use these models for **publishing** or **consuming** messages.

Now, what if, there is a need to change **properties** of the **OrderCreatedMessage** class. in this situation, all the publisher or subscriber which they use this message, should update their Nuget or there is no problem?

How we can set a version for messages or queues?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question clearly. But if you have created all your messages in the same NuGet packet think it's better to separate them by declaring an abstract class or interface and add it to the rest of your projects. But in this situation, if you make a change you need to update the Nuget package. if you have an instance of old Nuget consumers/publishers may use the older messages RabbitMQ.So if you want to use new properties you should update them

Comment: Also, you can add metadata to your messages. Check https://humus-amqp-module.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.0/articles/deployment.html - Message-Versioning section